# ThreadpoolExecutor for queueing up requests

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I need to queue all my requests to particular service and need to execute 2 requests at a time.All remaining threads will be in Queue. For that purpose I am using ThreadPoolExecutor object by setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize as 2. Whenever request comes, ThreadPoolExecutor handle that request to one of these threads. So these 2 threads will be there from application startup to till you shutdown server.I am simply using below statement.

```
threadpoolExecutorObject.execute(new RunnableObject());
```

1.I just want to know, Is there any better way to do this?

2.Our application server is sometimes hanging and not responding and we are restarting server. By any chance, Is the above implementation causing this problem?

3.I am leaving only above statement in my method. Do I need to do shutdown or anything else?

Comment: It should be a problem with the task that you are executing. If the task is hung/waiting for other resources, the other waiting threads will not be executed until the first two threads completes its task. Please share the details about the task which is executed using this thread pool executor.

Comment: I also recommend to collect the jstack information when the problem occurs again and that would help you identify the problem.